# SQL зачем-то меняет дату

Tags: mysql, sql

Когда я начинаю добавлять в таблицы записи с датой (13.04.2020), то в результате он начинается выдавать это (2013-04-20)
Может мне кто объяснить решение этой проблемы ?
Почему консоль перекидывает часть года в начало даты ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Левая сторона - это то, что набираю. Правая сторона - это то, что мне выдаёт.

Comment: похоже тебе стоит передавать дату в формате 2020.04.13

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 как вы добавляется (на каком языке, через консоль, etc)?

Comment: *Когда я начинаю добавлять в таблицы записи с датой (13.04.2020)* Как именно? *он начинается выдавать это (2013-04-20)* Правильно делает. Ему так предписано документацией. [The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html). И менять формат вывода ради тех, кто документацию не читает, он не станет.

Answer (score 3):

Вы путаете сами даты и формат их отображения.

Наиболее близкая аналогия с числами. Например, `1/2`, `0,5` и `0.50000e+0` - это одно и то же число, просто записанное в разных форматах.

Аналогично и у дат.

Даже в пределах одной и той же европейской цивилизации, имеющей общее летоисчисление используется несколько разных форматов записи: `ДД.ММ.ГГГГ`, `ММ/ДД/ГГГГ`, `ДД МММ ГГГГ` (месяц записан буквами) и т.д.

Чтобы не было путаницы, большинство информационных систем (если явно не указано иное) используют формат ISO 8601 `ГГГГ-ММ-ДД`. Он удобен двумя вещами:

1. Лексикографическая сортировка (алфавитная) совпадает с хронологической
2. Нет разночтений, в какой позиции стоит месяц, а в какой год.